# How to find the most important features learned during Deep Learning using CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano, deep-learning

I followed the tutorial given at this [site](http://wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/), which detailed how to perform text classification on the movie dataset using CNN. It utilized the movie review dataset to find predict positive and negative reviews.

My question is, is there any way to find the most important learned features from the model? Does Tensorflow/Theano has any support for this?

Thanks !

Comment: There is no support for this as finding the most important features is something you need to implement yourself and is part of the model.

Answer (score 2):

A word of warning: if you can trace the classification back to specific input features, it's quite possible that CNN is the wrong ML paradigm for your application.  Most text processing uses RNN, bag-of-words, bi-grams, and other simple linear combinations.

The structure of a CNN is generally antithetical to identifying the importance of individual features.  Because of the various non-linear layers, it is rarely possible to pick out any one feature as important; rather, the combinations of inputs form small structures of inference, which then convolve to form more complex structures, until the final output is driven by a series of neighbor relationships, cut-offs, poolings, and other items.

This is why back-propagation is so important to running CNNs: the causation chain does *not* reverse cleanly.  Otherwise, we'd reduce the process to a simple linear NN with one hidden layer.

If you want to analyze what's happening, try visualizing your intermediate layers.  There are various modules to help with that; for instance, try a search for "+theano +visualize +CNN -news" (the last is to remove the high-traffic references to Cable News Network).  There are plenty of examples in image processing; we won't know how much it might help your text processing, until you try it.